# Physics simulation accuracy

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I want to create an animation with a cup falling on a plate.
I encounter this error: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HWPJKGIEsMbaL5WniwBCojy_XnwbjaAa

Here are my rigid body settings, for the cup and plate.
[image]
How to fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stop the cup when it hits the plate try the "deactivation" under the Dynamics tab (lower-right corner on your first pic).
Otherwise setting are here:[image]

And it also helps if you increase the object's scales.